# Django import-export.admin customize：for xlsx sheets, and change the diff strategy

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a knotty problem. I used [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)
to import xlsx data. I have integrated it to Django admin by ImportExportModelAdmin. below is admin.py：

```
@admin.register(assets)
class data_import(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

But when I import data several times, I found it just save the newest data(the last) to model, I want save all data every time I import, and just use some columns to decide if the data is duplicated.How can I solve this?
model.py:

```
class station(models.Model):
    station_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Astation')

class assets(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, verbose_name = 'Aname')
    sn = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Asn', default=None)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(u'IP', blank=True, null=True)
    station = models.ForeignKey(station)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a resource class and override `get_instance` method and return False always

```
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget

class DataResource(resources.ModelResource):
    # UPDATE
    # If model has ForeignKey
    station = fields.Field(widget=ForeignKeyWidget(station, 'id'))

    def get_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
        # Returning False prevents us from looking in the
        # database for rows that already exist
        return False

    class Meta:
        model = assets # class name should be camelcase
        fields = '__all__' # If all column of table present in xlsx otherwise mention fields name.

@admin.register(assets)
class data_import(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = DataResource
```

Comment: Thanks,but didn't work. First file I import 10 data ,then I import second file that has 5 new data, Finally, however, just the new 5 data in my database,

Comment: update your question with Model code, Have you specified any field unique=True?

Comment: How are you updating `station` field of assets model are you using `ForeignKeyWidget` class of import_export.widgets package? also post some sample data you are uploading

Comment: I have added some data in **station**, like: id=1, name=A,...,and the file I import has (name,sn,ip,station),like:  name=cab, sn=123456, ip=1.1.1.1, station=1

Comment: Is the foreignkey caused this? how to deal with this?

Comment: I have update my answer for foreign key. Yes that can be a possible issue.

Comment: sorry, but that issue still exist

Comment: I have tried same scenario and after each import of same file new entry is being created in database. i have 15 records in file and after each import 15 new records are inserting in database.

Comment: Update your question with latest code, may be you are missing something.

Comment: I got it! It is the 'id' problem, The default field for object identification is 'id', but the id of each file I import was started at 1...Thanks a lot, wish you a happy day